# Link does not 'post' the right data to action. (only get last id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, logic, erb

I have a page that lists all news articles and an edit button beside them (manage).  The edit button takes you to the edit page and sends the data of its respective article. The edit button always chooses the last id generated.  What am I doing wrong with my loop?

---

Resources:

routes.rb

```
  get   '/news/manage', to: 'news#manage'
  match '/news/edit', to: 'news#edit', :via => :post
```

news_controller.rb

```
before_action do
  setup(session[:current_user_id])
end

def edit
  @article = News.find(params[:id])
end

def manage
end

private
  def setup(session)
    @user = User.find(session)
    @articles = News.all
  end
```

manage.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag '/news/edit', method: "post" do %>
  <%= @articles.each do |article| %>
        <%= content_tag :button, type: "submit" do %>
          <%= content_tag :i do %><%end%>
        <%end%>
      <%= content_tag :input, name: "id", value: article.id do %> <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :textarea, name: "content", rows: "20" do %>
    <%= @article.content.gsub(/\s+/, " ")%>
<%end%>
<%= content_tag :input, name: "id", type: "hidden", value: @article.id do %> <%end%>
```

Comment: It's not good practice to handle edit as POST request. edit should be GET request. You should provide link to user over button. You can write css to decorate link as button.

Comment: @AmitPatel Been struggling with finding out how to use get correctly.  Any good sources that can show me exactly what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your form has multiple generated elements with the same name : "id".  It doesn't know which one to use, so it uses the last one.

Now the thought....how do you make the name unique for each article?  This probably isn't the best solution but...don't

Make your form unique.  Change this code:

```
<%= form_tag '/news/edit', method: "post" do %>
  <%= @articles.each do |article| %>
        <%= content_tag :button, type: "submit" do %>
          <%= content_tag :i do %><%end%>
        <%end%>
      <%= content_tag :input, name: "id", value: article.id do %> <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end>
```

to this:

```
<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= form_tag '/news/edit', method: "post" do %>
        <%= content_tag :button, type: "submit" do %>
          <%= content_tag :i do %><%end%>
        <%end%>
      <%= content_tag :input, name: "id", value: article.id do %> <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end>
```

Answer (score 2):

First make following change in `routes.rb`

replace

```rb
match '/news/edit', to: 'news#edit', :via => :post
```

with

```rb
get '/news/:id/edit' => 'news#edit', as: :edit_news
```

then replace

```
<%= form_tag '/news/edit', method: "post" do %>
  <%= @articles.each do |article| %>
        <%= content_tag :button, type: "submit" do %>
          <%= content_tag :i do %><%end%>
        <%end%>
      <%= content_tag :input, name: "id", value: article.id do %> <%end%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_news(article) %>
<% end %>

this will create `Edit` link for each article and clicking on it will take you to edit page.
```

If you want to show link as button you need to write css.